# deadlock at pthread_cond_destroy()

Tags: linux, multithreading

my problem gdb output:

```
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt. 0x00007ffff7bcb86b in
__lll_lock_wait_private ()    from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7bcb86b in __lll_lock_wait_private ()    from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007ffff7bc8bf7 in _L_lock_21 ()    from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x00007ffff7bc8a6e in pthread_cond_destroy@@GLIBC_2.3.2 ()    from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x0000000000400ab5 in control_destroy (mycontrol=0x6020c0) at control.c:20
#4  0x0000000000400f36 in cleanup_structs () at workcrew.c:160
#5  0x0000000000401027 in main () at workcrew.c:201
```

Note: the program run in cygwin success, but run in ubuntu linux, it's deadlock.
The all sub threads join finished before deadlock.

The source code is from web: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cn/linux/thread/posix_thread3/thread-3.tar.gz

Answer (score 2):

The bug is in `control.c`:

```
int control_destroy(data_control *mycontrol) {
  int mystatus;
  if (pthread_cond_destroy(&(mycontrol->cond)))
    return 1;
  if (pthread_cond_destroy(&(mycontrol->cond)))
    return 1;
  mycontrol->active=0;
  return 0;
}
```

This was, presumably, supposed to destroy the mutex and the condition variable. But instead it destroys the condition variable twice.